# Probability of pulling out balls from a jar

Tags: probability

A jar contains 3 red balls, 4 white balls and 2 black balls. Balls are being pulled out and returned back to the jar forever.

I'm trying to calculate the probability that the first red ball that was pulled out came out before the first white ball that was pulled out?

Comment: Selecting a black ball doesn't matter, so ignore those.  The probability that the first meaningful choice is red is $\frac 37$.

Comment: @lulu $3/7$ is the answer? what about the white balls?

Comment: If you ignore the black balls, you have $3$ red and $4$ white, hence $3+4=7$ balls in total.  The probability that a randomly selected ball is red is therefore $\frac 37$.

Comment: think of it this way:  any given trial can be Meaningful or Irrelevant (if you get a black ball) with some probability (depending on the number of black balls).  Every Meaningful turn yields Red with probability $\frac 37$, and the Irrelevant turns never change that.

Comment: @lulu not sure about that i think its something different. maybe to define N to be the first red ball pulled out so before red we can pulled out only black so theres $(2/9)$^$(N-1)$ and then to multiple by the probability of getting red ball $(3/9)$. what do you think?

Comment: I think @Lulu is right. Black balls are irrelevant. Balls keep being returned. There are 7 ways to select first valid ball. 3 of those are red.

Comment: If you are skeptical, do it directly via recursion.  Let $P(r,w,b)$ denote the probability you want given $r$ red balls, $w$ white, and $b$ black.  You want $P(3,4,2)$ and it is easy to see that $P(3,4,2)=\frac 39\times 1+\frac 49 \times 0 + \frac 29\times P(3,4,1)$ and so on.

Comment: As another way to understand it:  suppose the balls are numbered $r_1,r_2,r_3, w_1,w_2,\cdots$.  Then we have $9!$ equally probable ways of listing them.  You are asking "in how many ways does the first red precede the first white?"?  Now I think you will agree that the placement of the black balls in the list is irrelevant....you have $7$ relevant balls $3$ of which are red, so the answer is $\frac 37$.

Comment: A Monte-Carlo-simulation confirms 3/7.

Comment: @TalShani You can think in converse probability. The required probability is equal to one minus the probability that you draw first $(n-1)$ black balls and at last one white ball. You´ll get an geometric series. The result is indeed $\frac37$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R,W,B$ be the count of the turn the first red, white, and black ball is drawn.

By the Law of Total Probability, the probability that the first red occurs before the first white is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R<W) & = {{\mathsf P(R=1)\cdot \mathsf P(R<W\mid R=1)}+{\mathsf P(W=1)\cdot \mathsf P(R<W\mid W=1)}+{\mathsf P(B=1)\cdot \mathsf P(R<W\mid B=1)}}\\ & = \tfrac 3 9\cdotp 1+\tfrac 49\cdotp 0+{\tfrac 29\cdotp \mathsf P(R<W\mid B=1)}\end{align}$$

Now, if a black ball is drawn on the first try we ignore it and start again, so:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R<W) & = \tfrac 3 9+\tfrac 29\cdotp \mathsf P(R<W) \\(9-2)\mathsf P(R<W)&=3\\ \mathsf P(R<W) & = \tfrac 37 \end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, the probability that the first red is drawn on try $t$ and the first white is drawn later, is the probability that red is drawn on try $t$ and black is drawn on all previous trys.   $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R<W) & = \sum_{t=1}^\infty \mathsf P(R=t, t<W) \\ &= \sum_{t=1}^\infty \tfrac {3}{9}(\tfrac 29)^{t-1}\\ &= \tfrac {3}{9}\cdotp\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\tfrac{2}{9})^{k}\\&=\tfrac 39\cdotp\tfrac{9}{7}\\&=\tfrac 37\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, since obviously, red or white must be drawn on the first draw that is not black (call it drawn $N$), then$$\begin{align}\mathsf (R<W) &= \mathsf P(R=N\mid R=N\cup W=N)\\ & = \tfrac{3/9}{7/9} \\ & = \tfrac 37\end{align}$$

---

All roads lead to home.